# SEARCH TABLE vs SCAN TABLE

Tags: sql, sqlite, explain

```
sqlite> .schema actor
CREATE TABLE actor (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, gender TEXT
  );
sqlite> explain query plan
   ...> select * from actor where id = '305453';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE actor USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
sqlite> explain query plan
   ...> select * from actor where name = 'Connery, Sean';
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE actor
sqlite>
```

---

`SEARCH TABLE actor USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)` is taking significantly less time compared to `SCAN TABLE actor`

---

It is obvious that `SCAN TABLE actor` is an exhaustive scan of `actor` table due to chance of duplication, but,

1) Are `SCAN TABLE` & `SEARCH TABLE` scanning B-TREE or sequence of records?

2) If it is B-Tree, then how `SEARCH TABLE` query faster?

Comment: The primary key is an index, it doesn't need to read every row.

Comment: @Barmar Firstly, are these queries scanning sequence of records or B-tree, in both cases.Because B-Tree with primary key is pretty faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SEARCH TABLE` means it uses an index, which is a fast way to find rows with a specific column value. The primary key is automatically indexed, for other columns you need to add an index explicitly with the `CREATE INDEX` command. Searching a B-tree like this is O(log n).

`SCAN TABLE` means it has to perform an exhaustive search, reading all the rows in the table. Scanning the entire table is O(n). This is done when you're matching a non-indexed column, like `name` in your example.

For more information about SQLite indexes see [Squeezing Performance from SQLite: Indexes? Indexes!](https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-indexes-indexes-c4e175f3c346). And detailed documentation of the design of SQLite indexes is in [Query Planning](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161784/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-search-table-vs-scan-table).